# PERMANOVA contrasts by combination of levels

Tags: r, vegan, two-way, compare-contrast

I started to create a script for a PERMANOVA contrasts by combination of levels using adonis function, but doesn't seem to be working a combination of levels matrix with adonis object created, my code was:

### Packages

```
require(vegan)
require(doBy)
require(wzRfun)
require(multcomp)
```

## Data set

```
data(mite)
A = c(rep(c(0), 30), rep(c(1), 30))
B = rep(c(rep(c(0), 15), rep(c(1), 15)), 2)
```

## Create data frame

```
A <- as.factor(A)
B <- as.factor(B)
species <- mite[1:60,]
```

## PERMANOVA with Jaccard index

```
man.com<-adonis(species ~ A * B, method = "jaccard",permutations=999)
man.com
```

### Two-Way PERMANOVA Contrasts

### Interaction

```
A_B<- interaction(A, B)
levels(A_B)
do.call(rbind, strsplit(levels(A_B), "\\."))


g0 <- adonis(species ~ A * B, method = "jaccard",permutations=999)
g1 <- adonis(species ~ A_B, method = "jaccard",permutations=999)

M <- LSmatrix(g0, effect=c("A","B"))
```

### Mean estimation

```
data.frame(g0=M%*%coef(g0), g1=coef(g1))
```

### Combination of levels

```
str(M)
grid <- attr(M, "grid")
```

### Matrix of contrasts between levels of treatement

```
B <- "b"
A <- "a"
spl <- interaction(grid[,2])
i <- 1:nrow(grid)
l <- split(i, f=spl)
contr <- lapply(l,
                function(row){
                    ## Contrast matrix parwise
                    a <- apc(M[row,], lev=levels(d[,2]))
                    rownames(a) <- paste(spl[row[1]],
                                         rownames(a), sep="/")
                    return(a)
                })
contr <- do.call(rbind, contr)
contr
```

### Constrasts

```
summary(glht(g0, linfct=contr),
        test=adjusted(type="fdr"))
```

Could somebody please help me,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you explain what is not working for you? you can definitely get more help

Comment: In mean estimation the script dont create LSmatrix

Comment: FWIW, this question was cross-posed to the R-sig-eco mail list today as well: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-ecology/2016-February/005283.html

Comment: Richard Erickson please post your answer here or in R-sig-eco mail, no problem!

Comment: Obviously `LSmatrix` does not know `adonis` objects. What made you believe it would?

Comment: What an honor Jari Oksanen, thank for you answer. Give you another solution for me?

Comment: `LSmatrix` was the first problem, but actually the smallest one. The procedures your try to apply are all for parametric models, and you would need things like *t*-values, `vcov` (variance-covariance matrices of parameters) etc. that do not exist in `adonis`. We do not use parametric tests with `adonis` but only permutation tests. You should build your procedure around those permutation tests.

Comment: Kay Cichini has written about test designs in `adonis`.  Here one entry, but there are others http://www.r-bloggers.com/two-way-permanova-with-vegan-function-adonis-using-customized-contrasts/

Comment: Thanks Jari Oksanen, I will read a Kay posts!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103329/discussion-between-leprechault-and-jari-oksanen).